# How to use ng-annotate directions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-annotate

how exactly do you run ng-annotate from the command line? Im trying to minify angular, angular_routes and my own script.js into one file. Ive tried `grunt uglify:app1` but it gives the injection error. My own code works when minified by itself but not when combined with the angular scripts.here is the grunt file

```
grunt.initConfig({
    ngAnnotate: {
        options: {
            singleQuotes: true,
        },
        app1: {
            files: {
                'min.js': ['angular.js','angular_routes.js','script.js'],

            },
        },


    },
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ng-annotate');
```

I dont know what the command is to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your grunt file:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['ngAnnotate']);
```

And then just run `grunt` in the console